# Error after deploying Sesame application into Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, sesame

I created an application using sesame dependencies:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.openrdf.sesame</groupId>
            <artifactId>sesame-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openrdf.sesame</groupId>
            <artifactId>sesame-repository-sail</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openrdf.sesame</groupId>
            <artifactId>sesame-sail-memory</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
```

It works when running it with the integrated Tomcat in Spring IDE.
 I deployed it  into Tomcat 7 but I get the following error when accessing one of the methods I used in my code: (same thing works in Spring)

java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.openrdf.repository.sail.SailRepositoryConnection.begin()V
    at org.openrdf.repository.event.base.NotifyingRepositoryConnectionWrapper.begin(NotifyingRepositoryConnectionWrapper.java:272)
    at org.openrdf.repository.manager.SystemRepository.initialize(SystemRepository.java:88)
    at org.openrdf.repository.manager.LocalRepositoryManager.createSystemRepository(LocalRepositoryManager.java:107)
    at org.openrdf.repository.manager.LocalRepositoryManager.createSystemRepository(LocalRepositoryManager.java:62)
    at org.openrdf.repository.manager.RepositoryManager.initialize(RepositoryManager.java:104)
    at com.mvc.API.StorageAPI.createNativeLocalRepository(StorageAPI.java:154)

At line 154 I have:
manager.initialize();

which is from:

File dataDir = new File(REPOSITORY_NAME);
RepositoryManager manager = new LocalRepositoryManager(dataDir);

RepositoryManager is an abstract class from Sesame which has an implemented method initialize(), LocalRepositoryManger inherits from it, but does not override the method initialize().
I also tried with Tomcat 6.0.37 and changed the sesame dependencies to 2.7.6
Do you have any idea why I get this error?

Thank you!

Comment: You also asked this question on the [Sesame discussion mailinglist](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=31409711) and got an answer there - was anything unclear?

Answer (score 0):

An [AbstractMethodError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AbstractMethodError.html) can only occur at runtime if the compiled code used to run the program is not identical to the code used to actually compile the program.

A common cause for this is that you are using a different version of a jar library to compile against than you are using to actually run the program - perhaps because there are two versions of the same jar on your classpath, or some other inconsistency in your build/run setup.

Check that your build path and/or your runtime classpath do not contain wrong or duplicate jar files. If you've recently changed your maven dependencies, make sure that your compile-time build path is regenerated, for example by using 'mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse' from the command line, or by using M2E's refresh option (if you're using the Eclipse M2E plugin, that is).